# Does Scipy recognize the special structure of this matrix to decompose it faster?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, scipy

I have a matrix whose many rows are already in the upper triangular form. I would like to ask if the command `scipy.linalg.lu` recognize this special structure to faster decompose it. If I decompose this matrix on paper, I only use Gaussian elimination on those rows that are not in the upper triangular form. For example, I will only make transformations on the last row of matrix `B`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2, 5, 8, 7, 8],
              [5, 2, 2, 8, 9],
              [7, 5, 6, 6, 10],
              [5, 4, 4, 8, 10]])
B = np.array([[2, 5, 8, 7, 8],
              [0, 2, 2, 8, 9],
              [0, 0, 6, 6, 10],
              [5, 4, 4, 8, 10]])
```

Because my square matrix is of very large dimension and this procedure is repeated thousands of times. I would like to make use of this special structure to reduce the computational complexity.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not automatically.

You'll need to use the structure yourself if want to. Whether you can make it faster then the built-in implementation depends on many factors (the number of zeros etc)

Comment: Do you have suggestions on the packages or routines that factorize this kind of sparse matrix?